# Bypass Form Validation when field hidden with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have recently returned to try learn some coding. I have been able to set up a nice looking form with the help of W3 schools and this website when asking specific questions.

After a few days of messing around I finally was able to get a field to appear hidden until its checked with JQuery. I now have the problem that it doesn't let me  pass to the next step as the code is trying to validate the hidden field which is blank.

Here is my code

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
 $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
   
if($(this).val()=="true")
{
    $("#otherAnswer").show();
}
else
{
       $("#otherAnswer").hide(); 
}
    
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color:  #bda576;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color:  #bda576;
}
 
 /* Checkbox code */
 /* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 /* The container */
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color:  #bda576;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
 <div class="tab"> 
  <label class="container">No
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="false" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  <label class="container">Yes
  <input type="radio" value="true" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="otherAnswer" id="otherAnswer"/>
</div>
 
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `var x, y, i, valid = true;` please don't make us do detective work - name your variables in a way that describes their use in the code..

Comment: So, you want to check if all elements in current tab should not be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add (y[i].style.display == "none")?valid = true:valid = false; check in your validation function which will check if input element is hidden.

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      //valid = false;
      (y[i].style.display == "none")?valid = true:valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
 $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
   
if($(this).val()=="true")
{
    $("#otherAnswer").show();
}
else
{
       $("#otherAnswer").hide(); 
}
    
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color:  #bda576;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color:  #bda576;
}
 
 /* Checkbox code */
 /* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 /* The container */
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color:  #bda576;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
 <div class="tab"> 
  <label class="container">No
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="false" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  <label class="container">Yes
  <input type="radio" value="true" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="otherAnswer" id="otherAnswer"/>
</div>
 
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! This is so simple yet does it perfectly. Look forward to learning with you all

Answer (score 0):

You re actually creating common validations for tabs, 
This will not work in most of the scenario but for your first tab you can do something like.
Check element's visibility

```
function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
}
```

If it is visible then only you need to check if it is empty.

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

// Where el is the DOM element you'd like to test for visibility
*function isHidden(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
}*

function validateForm() {

  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "" && !isHidden(y[i])) {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
 $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
   
if($(this).val()=="true")
{
    $("#otherAnswer").show();
}
else
{
       $("#otherAnswer").hide(); 
}
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color:  #bda576;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color:  #bda576;
}
 
 /* Checkbox code */
 /* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 /* The container */
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color:  #bda576;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
</style>
<body>

<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
 <div class="tab"> 
  <label class="container">No
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="false" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  <label class="container">Yes
  <input type="radio" value="true" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="otherAnswer" id="otherAnswer"/>
</div>
 
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function for checking that the input is hidden or not

```js
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the crurrent tab

    function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
        //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
    }

  function checkHiddenOrNot(el) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    return (style.display === 'none')
  }

    function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            var inputForNoChecked = $('#noRadio').is(':checked');
            if (y[i].value == "" && !checkHiddenOrNot(y[i])) {
                // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                y[i].className += " invalid";
                // and set the current valid status to false
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
    }
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == "true") {
            $("#otherAnswer").show();
        } else {
            $("#otherAnswer").hide();
        }

    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    #regForm {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 100px auto;
      font-family: Raleway;
      padding: 40px;
      width: 70%;
      min-width: 300px;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;  
    }

    input {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: Raleway;
      border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }

    /* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
    input.invalid {
      background-color: #ffdddd;
    }

    /* Hide all steps by default: */
    .tab {
      display: none;
    }

    button {
      background-color:  #bda576;
      color: #ffffff;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: Raleway;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    button:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }

    #prevBtn {
      background-color: #bbbbbb;
    }

    /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
    .step {
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      margin: 0 2px;
      background-color: #bbbbbb;
      border: none;  
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .step.active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
    .step.finish {
      background-color:  #bda576;
    }
     
     /* Checkbox code */
     /* Customize the label (the container) */
    .container {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 35px;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 22px;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
    .container input {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
    }

    /* Create a custom checkbox */
    .checkmark {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: #eee;
    }

    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }

    /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
    .checkmark:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
    }

    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
      display: block;
    }

    /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
    .container .checkmark:after {
      left: 9px;
      top: 5px;
      width: 5px;
      height: 10px;
      border: solid white;
      border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
     /* The container */
    .container {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 22px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
    .container input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }

    /* Create a custom checkbox */
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }

    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
        background-color:  #bda576;
    }

    /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }

    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
    .container .checkmark:after {
        left: 9px;
        top: 5px;
        width: 5px;
        height: 10px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
      <h1>Register:</h1>
      <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
     <div class="tab"> 
      <label class="container">No
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="false" name="radio">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
      <label class="container">Yes
      <input type="radio" value="true" name="radio">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <input style="display:none;" type="text" name="otherAnswer" id="otherAnswer"/>
    </div>
     
      <div class="tab">Name:
        <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Contact Info:
        <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Birthday:
        <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">Login Info:
        <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
        <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
      </div>
      <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
          <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
      <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
        <span class="step"></span>
      </div>
    </form>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had almost identical issues with the same exact javascript script - however instead of the typical name/email/phone inputs, i'm using it for a interview form - with textarea instead of input type - And sorry if it is confusing - i'm still learning!!!

Here's how I fixed (thru much examination)- 1st in the js there are  4 lines, (2 for `prevBtn` and 2 for `nextBtn`)

```
   function showTab(n)

    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
```

and they are for this div in the html:

```
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn"onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" id="nextBtn"onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
```

But I didn't have any buttons showing up After some trial and error, I examined the css for those buttons even tho I know it's just styling, I changed the button selector  and my tabs and buttons appeared.
Changed

```
    button {}
```

to

```
    #nextBtn,#prevBtn {}
```

I also added the `textarea` selector to this line in the

```
    function validateForm()

   y = x[currentTab].querySelectorAll("input, textarea");
```

Hope this helps and you get yours working.. Here's [an example](https://nwnmenzo.pw/site/interview_samp.html) of mine in action (except at the time of this posting Im having a snag with the output.. :-)